# How to model an irregular pentagon pattern?

Tags: modeling, objects, hard-ops

Has anyone an idea on how to model this kind of irregular pentagon pattern?[image: desired result]

I am using a displacement map, but it's very resource intensive and doesn't look quite accurate.

[image: my current 3D Model]

Comment: Don't you want to fake it with a normal or bump map? It will be super light. Apart from that I'm not sure why you're not glad with your current solution, it's pretty close to the reference picture, except the size and material are not exactly the same

Comment: I tried faking it with normal maps, but the refraction is not being rendered accurately.
The displacement map kinda works, but it creates strange artifacts on the hard edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To model it, make it first in two dimensions, as a repeatable pattern, then array it and use simple deform (bend) to make the tube.
Close it using "weld" and adjust the overall shape with a "mesh deform".

The repeatable pattern can be this kind of shape (selected part):

[image]

The object used for "simple deform" is the selected one below:

[image]

The modifiers:

[image]

[image]

A complement. In this case using a curve modifier could be much more easy than "mesh deform".
Just change the modifiers this way:

[image]

And you can adjust the diameter by changing the control points radius. Or even bend the shape as you want.

[image]

Another blend file for that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This pretty much solved my problem. Please PN me your PayPal Address, if you have one.

Comment: Thanks but no paid service for me here!!! just upvote and all is fine.

Comment: I have another question. Is there a way on how to distribute the pentagons evenly? As the tube gets stretched into the desired form, the pentagons are bending and stretching also. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in "general".

Answer (score 5):

Here is a try with a normal map, of course as it fakes 3D it won't appear as good as real 3D, if you want real 3D, use Lemon's method. Using *Displacement* will make your object uselessly heavy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try this method before. Unfortunately, the refraction has to be calculated correctly based on a "true" uneven surface.